# Can I send a Local Notification with no sound?

Tags: iphone, ios, uilocalnotification

I want to have a few local notifications with no display and no sound, but only a vibration.  I can get it to do no display, by simply setting `alertBody` to `@""`, but how can I send no sound?  I am thinking if I don't get a better way from you guys, that I will be able to just make a sound that is empty, add it to my project, then set soundName to that sound.  But is there any sort of default way to do this?

If I add a phony sound name it still plays the default notification sound.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can not disable sound because UILocalNotification does not provide any option for this. So better option is as you told in your question to use a empty sound file.

Comment: Wrong! It is possible to get push notification without a sound file! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841600/ios-push-notifications-how-to-specify-alert-and-badge-with-no-sound

Comment: @GuntisTreulands firstly read the question properly then comment any answer. Question is related to UILocalNotification not Apple Push Notification.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can add another sound file.

```
NSString *soundFile=@"temp.mp3"; 

UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    if (localNotification==nil) {
        return;
    }
    localNotification.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:60];
    localNotification.alertBody = @"Your alert message";
    localNotification.soundName = soundFile;
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

In above code just put the name of sound file which you have saved in your resources in place of "soundFile" string.

Comment: I want to use default sound

Answer (score 0):

You can not set sound.or

```
-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)responsewithCompletionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler{
NSDictionary * userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo;
if([response.notification.request.trigger isKindOfClass:[UNCalendarNotificationTrigger class]]) {}
else{}
//don't write UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound
completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
```

}